# Top and Left Menu Bar odoo 8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am new to odoo development. I am working on making a new page which will contain top menu and left menu bar.
My controller is:

```
@http.route('/test',auth='public')
def index(self,**kw):
    return http.request.render('test.index',{})
```

My template has:

```
<template id="index">
   *** I want to call or inherit template with top menu item and left menu bar
   <div class="body">
       My test body data
   </div>
</template>
```

i also tried using  but this uses website plugin which i don't want, i only need to show top and Left menu bar with my content in the center.

Can you please help me.
Really appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to you the website layout to bring w/ you the whole page structure, for instance:

```
<template name="My template" id="my_template">
  <t t-call="website.layout">
    <div id="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        [...]
      </div>
    </div>
  </t>
</template>
```

by doing this you are injecting your page content in website layout, [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/website/views/website_templates.xml#L183).

If you want to show only some parts of the layout, then override the layout to create your own, and instead of calling website.layout you call your custom version.